# Interface to call treeview expand/collapse functionality on client?

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Is there any build in javascript function to expand/collapse any treeview particular node from client?

Actually I am using treeview with checkboxes enabled and I want to have a particular node collapsed and unchecked initially, and when checked should be expanded.

Any built in thing or idea?
I couldn't find any way yet...

**Edit:**

I tried checking if collapsed nodes are invisibly(display:none or something) available on the page so that I can play with some javascript to make them visible on checkbox changed of parent node, but found they are not at all rendered on the page :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

I was wrong, it does render collapsed nodes with [display:none] and so my problem is solved.

I am now binding client onclick event on treeview and there I am making collapsed nodes visible when there parent node is checked, as per my requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share your solution.